# Promblem with creating sharp glossy glossy material for metal drinking bottle

Tags: materials

I'm trying to recreate this drinking bottle [image: drinking bottle]

which as you can see has quite a sharp reflection, so I first tried to use just a sharp glossy shader[image: bottle with glossy shader]

which doesn't look like any real object at all because it doesn't interact with light really. 
So instead i tried two things: I first mixed it with a normal glossy shader, which just created a weird high light, so then I mixed it with a diffuse shader which created a better result, but looks still is a little off, especially on the edges[image]

[image]

So, now to the actual question: how could I create the sharp reflection of the bottle, while still letting it interact with light normally, without creating diffuse high lights?

Comment: Further to bstnhnsl's answer, you might also want to look into the numerous references for car paint shaders in Blender/Cycles.  I think there might be some flakes in there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all:** if you want to have reflections on your bottle you need something in your scene to show in the reflection. as of now, you just have your light source, a grey plane and the ground background. that's not ideal to check how your material reflects things. (read the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104636/reflections-showing-wave-pattern-after-adding-plane/104637#104637) why those wavy reflections appear).

I'd recommend using an HDRi to light your scene. [here](https://hdrihaven.com) you can grab some for free.

**Material:**
I'd recommend using the principled Shader. it uses Fresnel to make the reflectiveness be dependent on the view angle.

[image]

that's a pretty basic setup, but you can work from there. I'd also recommend using a normal- or displacement map to mimic the bumps of your bottle.

Comment: Is it actually correct to set metallic to 1? Sure, it looks metallic, but the it's actually paint, that is not a metal. Does this matter?

Comment: looks to me like it's a metallic paint (which consists of small metal flakes  like car paint), so setting metallic to 1 isn't too far off. But you can also play with the values to make the material fit your needs. in cg there's no "actual correct". at the end it's the artists choice. "It's right if it looks right".